# Sequelize - Filter parents when specified related objects are not listed

Tags: sequelize.js

Hi all and thanks in advance for your responses,

I have the following associations with Sequelize:

```
const ForumUser = require('./models').ForumUser;
const UserTopics = require('./models').UserTopics;
const Topic = require('./models').Topic;

ForumUser.belongsToMany(Topic, {
  through: UserTopics,
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});

Topic.belongsToMany(ForumUser, {
  as: 'ForumUsers',
  through: UserTopics,
  foreignKey: 'topic_id'
});
```

I would like to retrieve topics when no moderators have responded (user with rank 7, 8, 23). I can filter parents when a moderator has responded but not the reverse.

I tried with this:

```
Topic.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'subject', 'last_post_time'],
    where: {
      locked: { $ne: '1' },
      hold: 0
    },
    include: [
      {
        attributes: ['userid'],
        model: ForumUser,
        as: 'ForumUsers',
        include: {
          attributes: ['username'],
          model: User
        },
        where: {
          rank: {
            $notIn: [7, 8, 23]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    order: [['last_post_time', 'DESC']],
    limit: 10
});
```

The problem is that I also retrieve all topics that contain at least one answer from a non-moderator.

Is there a way to filter parents who do not contain a specified relational object?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem by adding `required: false`

```
Topic.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'subject', 'last_post_time'],
    where: {
      locked: { $ne: '1' },
      hold: 0,
      '$ForumUsers.rank$': null
    },
    include: [
      {
        attributes: ['userid'],
        model: ForumUser,
        as: 'ForumUsers',
        include: {
          attributes: ['username'],
          model: User
        },
        where: {
          rank: {
            $in: [7, 8, 23]
          }
        },
        required: false
      }
    ],
    order: [['last_post_time', 'DESC']],
    limit: 10,
    subQuery: false
  }
```

This is equivalent to doing a left outer join instead of a default left join which will exclude all results that do not satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. It would be great if you could, for the future, provide some explanation apart from the code, so the readers can understand and apply in their own scenarios. :D